# Implementar autenticacion JWT en loopback

Tags: nodejs, rest, jwt, loopbackjs, loopback

Soy bastante nuevo usando NodeJS, asi que he intentado implementar una API REST con el framework de Loopback para intentar simplificar un poco el proceso. He escrito bien los modelos (hasta modificado endpoints) pero a la hora de conectar la API con el front (escrito en Angular), todo el código para los login y registro que encuentro (y que sé escribir) requieren un token JWT para la identificacion. El problema es que parece ser que Loopback envia un token uid2 por defecto, pero no encuentro manera de modificarlo, o de insertar alguna funcion sin pasar por auth0 o un gateway, cosa que quiero evitar a toda costa.
He buscado bastante, en Stackoverflow y Github sobre todo, y lo mas cercano que he encontrado es este "issue" en github
(https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1905#issuecomment-310382322) pero el código falla en este punto:

```
const data = jwt.verify(id, secretKey);
        cb(null, {userId: data.id});
```

Y no tengo idea de por que. Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El *issue* al que haces referencia es de hace 2 años. Eso es una eternidad hablando en términos de frameworks y desarrollo web. ¿Estás seguro que la documentación no plantea nada al respecto?

Comment: Seguro, loopback proporciona soporte nativo a OAuth 1.0/2.0 y similares, pero para jwt estoy viendo que tengo que usar un middleware....

Comment: Bien, y exactamente ¿cuál es el error que te arroja? ¿Podrías postearlo? Tengo cierta experiencia con JWT y tal vez lo pueda mirar. Veré de documentarme con Loopback para saber cómo ha de ir el middleware. Saludos

Comment: En el cliente: https://pastebin.com/w0Nutazr | En el servidor https://pastebin.com/ixxdAZba

Comment: ya me han respondido en stackoverflow.com https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602582/how-to-implement-jwt-auth-on-loopback-rest-api/55608969#55608969

Comment: No te seria mas sencillo generar un sdk con loopback (https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder) para angular, y luego usar LoopBackAuth para guardar el token que devuelve el login ? Si llegas a necesitar ayuda con eso te puedo dar una mano.